# Dialog not displaying from fragmentActivity in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to display a dialog inside the class that extends FragmentActivity.I have tried  in many ways.Atlast I tried [this link](http://vinaygopinath.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/alertdialog-using-fragment/). I have tried the samething but iam getting the following error message.

```
  05-14 10:15:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(2927): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
  05-14 10:15:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):   at   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1342)
  05-14 10:15:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
  05-14 10:15:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
  05-14 10:15:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):   at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:127)
  05-14 10:15:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):   at com.sriseshaa.ecgviewer.FragmentTabActivity$1$1.run(FragmentTabActivity.java:70)
  05-14 10:15:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
  05-14 10:15:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  05-14 10:15:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  05-14 10:15:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
  05-14 10:15:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  05-14 10:15:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  05-14 10:15:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  05-14 10:15:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
  05-14 10:15:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

FragmentTabActivity.java:70 is

```
   adFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

I have called the dialog by the following code snippet

```
          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  
          bundle.putString("title", "Message");  
          bundle.putString("message", StaticHelper.l);  
          bundle.putString("positive", "Ok");  
          bundle.putString("negative", "Cancel");  
          // bundle.putInt("id", mIndex++);  
          AlertDialogFragment adFragment = new AlertDialogFragment();  
          adFragment.setArguments(bundle);  
          adFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

What I have missed? and what is the problem in this? please help me.Thank u!!

Comment: Fragment is not supported on the SDK platforms older than HoneyComb, only when you add the android.support.v4 to your build environment, confirm you have done that

Comment: yeah, I am using android-support-v4.jar in my project

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to display an alertdialog what is your problem of using **AlertDialog.Builder** as following.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    dialog.setTitle("Title");
    dialog.setMessage("Message");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        }
       });
       dialog.setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
      });
      dialog.show();
```

Comment: I am calling the dialog from the class that extends "FragmentActivity" not "Activity" or "Fragment".In this i cant use "getActivity()"

Comment: i have edited the answare if you are in activity just use this keyword as the context.  if you are in fragment use getActivity() .

Comment: I know..but here  i am in _class A extends FragmentActivty_

Comment: did you try with above code ? if yes what is the error you get.

Comment: If I use use _this_ or _getActivity()_ The eclipse shows _The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new Runnable(){}) is undefined_  or _The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}_ error message

Comment: There should not be a problem of using above code in FragmentActivty.Above code is working properly. Why did you use new Runnable(){}) ?